# How to edit google app script outside of the browser, e.g., in emacs or vim?

Tags: vim, google-apps-script, emacs

I want to edit GS (google app script) files in a decent editor (Emacs or VIM) and keep it under git, so I need to be able to install it to run it.
Right now I copy the whole file and paste it into the code window in the browser, which is clearly suboptimal.

I wonder if there is a way to do it.

For some reason, [Edit With Emacs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-with-emacs/ljobjlafonikaiipfkggjbhkghgicgoh) does not work with the script editor.

Comment: Please think of this as one of many methods. I always create GAS on own editor using [this CLI tool](https://github.com/tanaikech/ggsrun). I write a gs script, push it to GitHub and run it. All of these are performed on own terminal. If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: You could try Atomic Chrome (Chrome) + atomic-chrome (Emacs).  I think there's a Vim client too.  It doesn't work with fancy textboxes like gmail, but works great with simple ones like stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The google apps script
[Importing and Exporting Projects guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/import-export) details using the [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/)

**Note:** Import/Export of scripts is [limited](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/import-export#features_and_limitations) to [Standalone scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)

> 6. Only standalone scripts can be imported or exported. Container-bound scripts cannot be accessed through the Google Drive REST API.

- This [Google repo](https://github.com/google/google-apps-script-samples/tree/master/import_export_development) details how to work with scripts in a local dev environment
- It uses [node-google-apps-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-google-apps-script) which is really all you need to import/export your script project to a local machine and back to Google

It is a little bit of work setting it up; there are quite a few steps to work through

Comment: Does this mean that if the script is connected to a spreadsheet (i.e., uses `SpreadsheetApp`), it will not be supported?

Comment: If you get to the script by opening a spreadsheet and then going to the menu > Tools > Script editor... That is a [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound). If the script file is in your Google Drive, it is a [standalone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) that can then be deployed as an [add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/) for your sheet, doc, form etc. They all can use `SpreadsheetApp` . You can go to [script.google.com](https://script.google.com) to start a new standalone and it will save to your Drive

Comment: It can also be used as a [Library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries) in other scripts

Comment: As an update, the mentioned package is deprecated. There is a tool named clasp, which implements such feature: https://github.com/google/clasp, if anyone interested.

Answer (score 5):

Despite this question is a bit old, I consider it could be useful for someone still wanting to edit App Scripts outside the browser.

There is a tool named `clasp` which aims to provide a way to edit an app script project in a local environment: https://github.com/google/clasp.

You just need to install via:

```
npm install -g @google/clasp
```

And enable the Google Apps Script API: https://script.google.com/home/usersettings

To use it, you should include a `package.json` via `npm init` (tested with version 2.4.0) and then make:

```
clasp login
clasp clone "projectID"
```

Afterwards, you could edit the files with your favorite editor. Finally, you could push the changes via:

```
clasp push
```

For more information, please check the repository of the project, pointed out above.